# How to call dynamic modal pop up on click dynamic link using in laravel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have dynamic link and each link is associated with modal pop up.

```
@foreach($image_data as $image)
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$image->image_id}}">
    <img src="{{asset('public/user_images/')}}/{{$image->image_name}}">
  </a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="{{$image->image_id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <img src="{{asset('public/user_images/')}}/{{$image->image_name}}">
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 @endforeach
```

What javascript or something else should I use to pop up this model ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){

      $('#modalID').fadeIn();

});
```

## modalID has to be determined by a data-attribute that you can give to your buttons. For example

```
<button type="button" class="open" data-dismiss="modal" data-id={{$image->image_id}}>
```

And then in JavaScript add

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){

    let modalID = '#' + $(this).data('id');
    $(modalId).fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: I added class in my image link (link_img) then final js code is <script>
$('.link_img').on('click', function(){
      let modalID = '#' + $(this).data('id');
      $('#modalID').fadeIn();

});
</script> but not working

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="modal-open"` to your `a`s

jQuery method

```
$('.modal-open').on('click', function() {
  $( '#'+$(this).data('target') ).show();
})
```

Typing from my head so there could be typos.

If the `a`s and `.modal`s are added dynamically then:

```
$(this).on('click','.modal-open', function() { ...
```

Comment: $('.link_img').on('click', function() {
  $( '#'+$(this).data('target') ).show();
})   is not working